# Is there a way to XSLT to echo out the XML powering it?

Tags: xml, design-patterns, xslt, serialization, reflection

I am using XSLT to transform XML. Is there a way for the XSLT to spit out the XML that is feeding it?  Something like:

```
<xsl:echo-xml />
```

Comment: Spit it out to where, and for what purpose? How about running the XSL in a debugger?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a number of possible solutions, explained in detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following copies the full XML to the result tree:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="." />
```

If you want to send that to the "message output", you can just wrap this like that:

```
<xsl:message>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:message>
```

Answer (score 8):

> Basically I am using some XSLT to
>   transform XML, is there a way for the
>   XSLT to spit out the XML that is
>   feeding it? Something like:

**The easiest and shortest way**:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/"/>
```

This outputs the current XML document.

```
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
```

This outputs the subtree rooted by the current node.

**However, XSLT programmers use mostly the following (identity rule):**

```
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
```

When this is the only template in the stylesheet, the complete XML document on which the transformation is applied is output as result.

**Using the identity rule is one of the most fundamental XSLT design patterns**. It makes extremely easy such tasks as copying all nodes but specific ones for which a specific processing is performed (such as renaming deleting, modifying the contents, ..., etc)/

Answer (score 0):

Use a template with the `name()` XPath function and angle bracket entities to output the node names:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="serialize.xml"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            >
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" version="" indent="yes" standalone="no" media-type="text/html" omit-xml-declaration="no" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" />

<xsl:template match="xsl:stylesheet">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="serialize"/>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="serialize">
      &lt;<xsl:value-of select="name()" />&gt;
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="serialize"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For further information, Jeni Tennison explains templates for [copying XML nodes to HTML](http://www.biglist.com/lists/xsl-list/archives/200111/msg01302.html) as well as [serializing external XML documents](http://www.biglist.com/lists/xsl-list/archives/200110/msg00551.html) on XSL-List